# camera position using 3d-2d motion estimation in monocular visual odometry

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, pose-estimation

In paper **Visual Odometry Part I**,it said that we can get camera position using 3d-2d motion estimation for the monocular case(It needs three images).

So, I got Rvec and tvec from function solvePnPRansac using 3d-2d motion estimation.

The question is how can I get camera position and draw its trajectory from Rvec and tvec.
The following two formulas are right?

> 1.Rcur=Rvec * Rcur
>
> 2.tcur=tcur+scale*(Rcur * tvec)

Beacuase I find [Avi Singh](https://avisingh599.github.io/vision/monocular-vo/) use them in 2d-2d motion estimation.

Is there any paper about monocular visual odometry using 3d-2d motion estimation to recommend.

Answer (score 0):

The `Rvec` and `tvec` you get from `solvePnP` are your current pose. You shouldn't have to do anything with them.

The formulas you have would apply if `Rvec` and `tvec` represent pose relative to the previous one, computed from the Essential matrix.

Comment: In 2d-2d motion estimation I can draw trajectory with x and z (camera pose) from tcur after calculation.In this condition how can I draw it? tvec?

Comment: Yes. `tcur = tvec`, and `Rcur = Rvec`.